# finding eigen vector for double eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 1  \\
        0 & 1 &  0 \\
        -2 & -2 & 3  \\
           \end{bmatrix} $

$\begin{bmatrix}
        - \lambda & -1 & 1  \\
        0 & 1- \lambda &  0 \\
        -2 & -2 & 3- \lambda \\
           \end{bmatrix} $

I got the eigen value is, $\lambda = 1,1,2$
,but when finding eigen vector
i got:

when $\lambda =1$,
$\begin{bmatrix}
        - \lambda & -1 & 1  \\
        0 & 1-\lambda  & 0 \\
        -2 & -2 & 3-\lambda  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        x  \\
        y \\
        z   \\
        \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
        0  \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$ 
$x=-y+z$

eigen vector = $\left( \begin{matrix} -1 \\ 1\\0\end{matrix} \right)t+\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\0\\1\end{matrix} \right)s$

and when $\lambda =2$,
$\begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
        0  \\
        2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

the problem is, the answer in my book for $\lambda=1$ is
$\begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
        0  \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}s$+
$\begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
        1  \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}t$ 
is my computation wrong for $\lambda =1$?

Comment: No! Both answers are correct

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar thanks but can you show me how can i produce the one from my book?

Comment: There's an error in your computation ogf the eigenvalues: it's  $1$ which is a double eigenvalue, not $2$. A simple eigenvalue cannot have an eigenspace of dimension $2$.

Comment: @bernard yes thanks sorry for typo.

Comment: Well you can see that the eigenvectors from your book also satisfy $x+y=z$

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar yes but can i find it using my calculation above? $\left( \begin{matrix} -y+z\\ y\\z\end{matrix} \right)$

Comment: Yes, use $y=z=1$ and $y=0,z=1$

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar did you find it by substitute $x=0$ or $z=0$ or $y=0$ to $x+y=z$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 1  \\
        0 & 1 &  0 \\
        -2 & -2 & 3  \\
           \end{bmatrix}.$$
With eigenvalues $1$ (2x) and $2$ (1x). To determine the eigenvectors for eigenvalue $1$ we do the following:
$$A-I = \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1 & 1  \\
        0 & 0 &  0 \\
        -2 & -2 & 2  \\
           \end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1 & 1  \\
        0 & 0 &  0 \\
        0& 0 & 0  \\
           \end{bmatrix}.$$
An eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ must satisfy: $(A-I)\mathbf{v} = 0$ so: $$\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1 & 1  \\
        0 & 0 &  0 \\
        0& 0 & 0  \\
           \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
We can see that $x=z-y$ must hold. Note that there are two null rows so we get two eigenvectors. Now we can choose two eigenvectors such that $x=z-y$ and that one eigenvector is no multiple of the other eigenvector. You may start with $x=0$ then it follows that $y=z$ so $\mathbf{v}_1=[0, y, y]^T$ will do for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$. We can choose $y=0$ then it follows that $x=z$ so $\mathbf{v}_2 = [x,0,x]^T$ will do for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. We can also choose $z=0$ which gives us $x=-y$ so $\mathbf{v}_3 = [x,-x,0]^T$ will do for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now we can choose two of those three, and these are our eigenvectors for eigenvalue $1$. Note that it can't be all three because $\mathbf{v}_1$ is linear dependent from $\mathbf{v}_2$ and $\mathbf{v}_3$.

Comment: thankyou so much!!

Comment: sorry one more question, from the three eigen vector for eigen value 1, is there any condition to choose the eigen vector? i mean is it need to be linear independent to each other? and what is the relation of linear independent and linear dependent with eigen vector here? thanks!!

Comment: Eigenvectors need to be linear independent! Always. This is very nice because if you computed your eigenvectors you can check if this is correct. If it isn't, then you made a mistake. Furthermore, there are infinite possibilities, however mostly eigenvectors are chosen on their simplicity (so with no fractions and as low as possible).

Comment: and also did you mean that v2 is linear dependent to v1 &v3? because $v1+v3=v2$, so for $\lambda=1$ the eigen vector will be v1&v2 or v3&v2?

Comment: v1 can be made using v2 and v3, v2 can be made using v1 and v3, v3 can be made using v1 and v2. So you just need to use two of them

Comment: oh okay,because the nullity is two so there are two eigen vector, two vector has to be linear independent in order to be eigen vector, and i can use $tv1+sv2=0$ to check whether it is linear independent or not?

Comment: For two vectors v1 and v2 it is easy to see if they are linear dependent: $v1 = k*v2$ for any $k$ then they are linear dependent.

Comment: yes, but i saw some problems that the questions want vector eigen that orthogonal to each other, if the equation dont produce vector eigen that orthogonal to each other, then i have to think the combination by myself?